# Format Column Headers during Pipe Delimited Concatenation (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation, alias, sqlplus

**Overview:** I am tasked with providing a data extract from an Oracle database as a pipe-delimited output text file. I will be using SQLPlus to do this on the server where the data lives. Ordinarily, this task is not beyond my experience, but this time, the business desires column headers to be present.

Consider the following five columns that I need to output:

```
SELECT
    a.USER_NAME || '|'
    || a.LAST_NAME || '|'
    || a.FIRST_NAME || '|'
    || b.PRODUCT_PURCHASED || '|'
    || c.DATEPURCHASED
FROM ...
WHERE ... ;
```

This SQL works fine, where the output looks like:

```
omnusruthius|ruthius|omnus|stackoverflow_prod|19-APR-16
```

However, the business wants it to look like:

```
USER_NM|LAST|FIRST|PROD|EFFECTIVE_DATE
omnusruthius|ruthius|omnus|stackoverflow_prod|19-APR-16
```

**Problem:** So the objective here is essentially to output the first row with custom-named column headers (aliases), as shown above. So my first approach was to try something like:

```
    SELECT
    a.USER_NAME AS USER_NM || '|'
    || a.LAST_NAME AS LAST || '|'
    || a.FIRST_NAME AS FIRST || '|'
    || b.PRODUCT_PURCHASED AS PROD || '|'
    || c.DATEPURCHASED AS EFFECTIVE_DATE
    FROM ...
    WHERE ...
```

Unfortunately, I receive:

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

I'm not sure how that would help anyway, as the original SQL output without aliases does not show column headers in the first row anyway. Remember, this is through the command line (SQLPlus), not Toad or some other RDMS.

So then I tried:

```
SELECT 
   'USER_NM', 'LAST', 'FIRST', 'PROD', 'EFFECTIVE_DATE' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT
    a.USER_NAME || '|'
    || a.LAST_NAME || '|'
    || a.FIRST_NAME || '|'
    || b.PRODUCT_PURCHASED || '|'
    || c.DATEPURCHASED
FROM ...
WHERE ...
```

Which gives the following error:

> ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns

I feel so close to the solution, what am I missing here? Any help will be appreciated!

**Edit:** Just a note to a future reader, both answers here will help you solve this problem, but upon further tweaking, I realize we've all been overthinking the solution. I'm not going to propose a new solution as the change is trivial, but consider doing the following instead:

```
SELECT 'USER_NM|LAST|FIRST|PROD|EFFECTIVE_DATE' FROM DUAL;
SELECT a.USER_NAME AS USER_NM || '|'
|| a.LAST_NAME AS LAST || '|'
|| a.FIRST_NAME AS FIRST || '|'
|| b.PRODUCT_PURCHASED AS PROD || '|'
|| c.DATEPURCHASED AS EFFECTIVE_DATE
FROM ...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY ... ;
```

**The key here is the use of the semicolons in SQL*Plus**. That first SELECT statement is completely independent from the second; no UNION is necessary as the output of the first query is automatically displayed immediately before the output of the second query. Both can have their own rules, which is especially convenient if your latter query is much more complicated. I can confirm the above query is working, and I'm surprised it took me that long to make that realization...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged the question with SQL*Plus, you can use [the PROMPT command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve032.htm) to generate the header, which avoids complications ordering the results with a union:

```
PROMPT USER_NM|LAST|FIRST|PROD|EFFECTIVE_DATE

SELECT
a.USER_NAME AS USER_NM || '|'
|| a.LAST_NAME AS LAST || '|'
|| a.FIRST_NAME AS FIRST || '|'
|| b.PRODUCT_PURCHASED AS PROD || '|'
|| c.DATEPURCHASED AS EFFECTIVE_DATE
FROM ...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY ...
```

That takes the headings out of the SQL and into the client realm, where it arguably belongs. This also works in SQL Developer, and other clients may be able to do something similar. It won't work if you run the query on its own from another client, or over JDBC, or whatever; but then whatever is running the query can (and maybe should) provide the header in that case too.

If you aren't already, you could also consider doing `SET HEADING OFF` or `SET PAGESIZE 0` to suppress the column headings from the query itself (though from what you said you're already doing that); and possibly `SET EMBED OFF`, though I don't think that's needed unless you do a separate query to generate the header line.

Comment: Using PROMPT works nicely. Could you elaborate on the second part of your post regarding SET HEAD OFF and SET EMBED OFF? Right now I have:
SET DEFINE ON, SET PAGESIZE 0, SET HEADING ON, SET FEEDBACK OFF, SET ECHO OFF, SET SQLBLANKLINES OFF, SET TRIMSPOOL ON, SET TRIMOUT ON, SET LINESIZE 2000

Comment: I couldn't remember off-hand if you needed to set embed on to prevent a blank line, but I think that's only if you have two queries, not a prompt. So looks like you can ignore that,. Your `set pagesize 0` is trumping `set heading on` - with that set to zero [you don't get headings](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG095), or page breaks, etc. So `set head[ing] off` would be redundant too.

Comment: I'm going with this answer, as it is optimized for SQL*Plus and is independent of potential future business requirement changes (i.e. sorting on a different field). Additionally, it actually gives more flexibility for the naming and styling of the top row (i.e. lowercase, spaces are legal, etc.) compared to the strict no-space, all capital demands of SQL column headers. Ultimately, this SQL is spooled to a text file, so this implementation is perfect for my needs. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @OmnusRuthius - vkp's approach lets you use anything you like in the header row too, since it's just a string literal. You aren't restricted to the original column names or the object naming rules. (Actually, it will also allow a longer header; prompt will limit you to < 2500 chars I believe, from a SQL\*Plus line length restriction, while the string literal in a query will allow 4k, or even 32k from 12c)

Comment: Good point Alex, that's an important correction. I realize now that as far as formatting the strings, either implementation works. I do, however, still prefer PROMPT as it is as simple and unaffected by ordering rules.

Comment: @OmnusRuthius - look at the last part of the last sentence of my answer; that's the query I meant, and which might need `embed` set. I nearly added it as an example but there isn't much benefit over the prompt - you're just hitting the database, for no real reason, unless you're hitting the 2.5k char limit. It's also basically vkp's answer but without the `union all` line.

Answer (score 3):

When concatenating make sure the header is a single string. Because you are concatenating the values in columns to be on one row.

If comma separation is used, as you have it in the question, the result block should also have 5 columns,which is not the case.

```
SELECT 
   'USER_NM|LAST|FIRST|PROD|EFFECTIVE_DATE' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT
    a.USER_NAME || '|'
    || a.LAST_NAME || '|'
    || a.FIRST_NAME || '|'
    || b.PRODUCT_PURCHASED || '|'
    || c.DATEPURCHASED
FROM ...
WHERE ...
```

Edit: The columns can also be sorted.

```
SELECT 'USER_NM|LAST|FIRST|PROD|EFFECTIVE_DATE' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
    a.USER_NAME || '|'
    || a.LAST_NAME || '|'
    || a.FIRST_NAME || '|'
    || b.PRODUCT_PURCHASED || '|'
    || c.DATEPURCHASED
FROM ...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY DATEPURCHASED) --add any other columns needed
```

Comment: This will be fine if you don't need sorting. If you need to sort by user_name or by last_name, the header row will fall wherever it may.

Comment: what do you mean by sorting here? see the edited answer with sorting as well.

Comment: The OP did not mention it, but it is very likely he will need the list "ordered by" somehow ("sorted" - my bad, should have said "ordered by"). Without the ORDER BY clause, the rows will not be ordered in any way and it is not guaranteed the header row will be at the top. With the ORDER BY clause you added, it is almost certain the header row will NOT be at the top. ORDER BY is processed only AFTER the union, not before!

Comment: have you ever tried this before?i suggest you check it for yourself. The sorting takes place for the results. Not for the string header.

Comment: Vkp, thanks for the quick response. This is definitely helping me progress. @mathguy is correct in his assumption that I will need to order this data output. My apologies for not specifying earlier. If it helps, I know exactly the field it will be sorted on: date. This extract will be a job that occurs nightly, taking the previous day's data and providing a report to the business.

Edit: Just saw your edit. I will report back when I have some data to test with.

Comment: @mathguy - did you miss the subquery in the second branch of the union? The results of that will be sorted before the union is applied. (Without that the order by would error as the column name doesn't exist in the first branch). On the other hand, I don't think it's *guaranteed* that the union-all will preserve the order - I've never seen this not work, but it's feasible it could break in a future release. Unlikely, but possible.

Comment: Yes, I missed the subquery (I am not sure the answer wasn't edited to make it a subquery - but I won't get into that, I may be completely wrong). And indeed, at least relational theory does not promise that the order will be preserved after the union, if the ordering is done in the subquery; that is based on physical implementation and we rely on it at our own risk.

Comment: @mathguy..*I am not sure the answer wasn't edited to make it a subquery - but I won't get into that, I may be completely wrong*..you should look at the answer before commenting.look at the edits if needed.

Comment: @vkp, This method is probably "best practice" to approach this in a traditional SQL way. There is no reason this answer is wrong, but the other answer is quite specific to my case, especially in regards to SQL*Plus. I appreciate your time and assistance regardless!

Comment: @OmnusRuthius..saw your edit. that is one more way to do it. I was not aware of that until now :) i just tested the same and it works well.